# libcurl + openssl cannot download files bigger than 2GB

Tags: c++, curl, openssl, libcurl

I'm trying to download a file using libcurl 7.20.0 and openssl 0.9.8l (but I updated the libraries to 7.29.0 and 1.0.1e), Windows 7 and everything is compiling for amd64 to download a big file. I am using curlpp as a wrapper for curl. The problem is, as soon as it reaches 2GB the download stops with the error `Failed writing body (0 != 8999)`. The code I use to do the request is:

```
boost::shared_ptr<curlpp::Easy> curl_request(boost::make_shared<curlpp::Easy>());
curl_request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::HttpVersion(CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0));
curl_request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Timeout(3600));
curl_request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::SslVerifyHost(0));
curl_request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::SslVerifyPeer(0));
curl_request->setOpt(new curlpp::options::Url(request_uri));
if (cookies.size() == 0) {
    curl_request->setOpt(new curlpp::options::CookieList("dummy"));
} else {
    BOOST_FOREACH(const std::string &cookie, m_cookies) {
        curl_request->setOpt(new curlpp::options::CookieList(cookie));
    }
}
curl_request->setOpt(new curlpp::options::Post(true));
curl_request->setOpt(new curlpp::options::PostFields(query_string));
curl_request->setOpt(new curlpp::options::WriteStream(stream.get()));

try {
    curl_request->perform();
} catch (std::exception &ex) {
    error = true;
    std::cerr << "caught Unknown error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
```

**EDIT** The stream is a stringstream and I am using MS VS 2008

Comment: What operating system? Is it 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Have you set CURLOPT_VERBOSE and CURLOPT_HEADER to 1 to see what is actually coming back from the server?  A 2GB limit seems really familiar as an HTTP specific issue (back in the 1990's a LOT of file systems has 2GB limits, so I think that people considered it an acceptable limit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a libcurl or OpenSSL limitation. This is either your file system (FAT?) or WriteStream implementation (or similar) that prevents this from working.

The error message seems to imply that suddenly a write to disk fails, and that is probably when the write overflows the maximum supported size.

Comment: That may very well be. I am writing to a stringstream.

Comment: so, there was a problem while writing to the stringstream after 2gb. I changed for a ofstream and everything worked fine.